# Can Dreamweaver show a list of variables, functions, class?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Is there a window in [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) that shows all variables and functions defined in the current document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you ***right click*** on the current document, you will see `Functions` context menu which contains the methods used.

Comment: @yes: I have not seen in separate window in it :)

Answer (score 10):

Another trick is to edit the toolbars xml file and uncomment the code nav button.

This gives you a toolbar button you can click to list the methods, rather than right clicking and selecting functions from the context menu.

Still not as good as a permanently visible pane, but one less click than the right click > functions context menu.

Open this file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\Toolbars\toolbars.xml`

Uncomment this block:

```
<menubutton id="DW_CodeNav"
    image="Toolbars/images/MM/codenav.png"
    MMString:tooltip="DW_CodeNav/menubutton/tooltip"
    enabled="dw.getFocus() == 'textView' || dw.getFocus() == 'html'"
    menuID="DWCodeNavPopup"
    update="onViewChange"/>
```

Restart Dreamweaver for the changes to be applied.

Code Nav icon `"{}"` appears at the end of the Document toolbar. The toolbar with (code|split|design).

Comment: I am stunned at how useful this is, and stupefied that there is no way to enable hidden features like this in the preferences pane.

Answer (score 4):

No, Dreamweaver, at least through CS5, does not have a window that lists variables and functions in the document. The CS5 code hinting engine is pretty good, so it should at least allow you to quickly type your code, but if you need a list outside of the document itself, there is no such thing.

There used to be an extension that would list functions defined in the page in a floating panel, Interakt's MX Code Pack, but it is no longer available as Interakt was acquired by Adobe, and their products subsequently "retired":
[MX Coder Pack](http://www.interaktonline.com/Products/Dreamweaver-Extensions/MXCoderPack/EOL/)

Comment: No, I'm sure that Adobe acquired Interakt for other reasons, the Dreamweaver extensions were simply an eventual casualty of the acquisition.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic but I thought I would update it since I submitted a feature request to Adobe to implement an "outline view" which would address OP's original question.  The feature would list functions inside of a page similar to how other IDE tools like Eclipse do it.  Dreamweaver currently does this for JavaScript functions only but this feature request would enable it for other types of pages as well (`cfml`, `php`, `asp`) and also let you see the DOM outline for any page.

Feel free to submit your request to Adobe here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&loc=en

Be sure to reference enhancement request `#3812052`. If enough people ask for this feature, perhaps Adobe will listen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. It could be posted as a comment to the question, however. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't intended as an answer but I thought it would be helpful.  Because I'm a new user with a low reputation I couldn't make a comment but I still wanted to contribute the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have no sulution for the variables, but for functions I use a little trick:

I do a search (ctrl+f) for the string "function " and the press "find all" this'll show the result window with all lines with "function "in it. Double clicking a line in the result window will take your to the appropriate function.

You can make something with regular expression where you search for function ({some chars}){ to be absolutely certain to only get function declarations.

You can then save this query and load it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed code hinting is the only way I've been able to view a functions list in CS5. The HOTKEY for code hinting is ctrl+spacebar.